# Vectorized sort of 2D numpy array columns independently

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, vectorization

There must be a simple vectorized way to sort independently all columns in a 2D numpy array without using a for cycle.

```
input_arr = np.array([[6,4],[3,1],[2,5]])

out_arr =np.empty_like(input_arr)
for c,column in enumerate(input_arr.T):
    out_arr[:,c] = np.sort(column)
```

```
Expected results:
unsorted:
[[6 4]
 [3 1]
 [2 5]]

columns_sorted:
[[2 1]
 [3 4]
 [6 5]]
```

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.sort(np.array([[6,4],[3,1],[2,5]]).T).T
```

EDIT:

Better and simpler solution, thanks to [@user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483203/user3483203)

```
np.sort(np.sort(np.array([[6,4],[3,1],[2,5]]), axis=0)
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: `np.sort(input_arr, axis=0)`?